# How to find reliable trusted profitable passive income residing in Eastern Europe?

Tags: real-estate, income, europe, passive-income

I would like to stop working and receive some passive income from anything that can generate income.
I live and reside in Eastern Europe (Ukraine).
I don't trust Ukrainian banks since they are not trustworthy and not reliable.
Many people used to have savings in Soviet Union state bank including my grandparents and they lost every savings they had.
Many private banks were established in Ukraine after it has gained independence from Soviet Union in 1991, however, many of them bankrupted and many depositors lost all or major part of their deposits.
I have around 10-15 k UAH expenses (around 559.08 USD) monthly on food (I don't eat at restaurants or cafes since it is more expensive to buy a meal there than to simply buy products at supermarket and cook at home ).
I have around 4500 UAH expenses (around 167.72 USD) monthly for payments for utilities (electricity, water supply, internet connection supply, gas supply etc.)
I would like to have some passive income which would cover my expenses.

I spend a lot on food since I need to buy food for myself, for my mother who is retired and doesn't work and doesn't receive salary and for my grandmother who is also retired and also doesn't work and doesn't receive salary. Also I pay utilities payments for two apartments, the one I live in and the one I used to live in where my grandmother still lives with my aunt. I support my mother and my grandmother since my aunt doesn't earn much money.

Also if it is possible to generate more passive income than just to cover my expenses, I would be interested in that as well for example to invest in some real estate.
I would like to buy or build a house in Ukraine. However, it is not so simple.
Due to Ukrainian law, every Ukrainian citizen and resident has a right to receive a free land plot but there is no clear way to implement that right and receive it. Many people pay bribe to receive some land plot for "free" but the cost of that bribe might be bigger or equal to the cost of the land plot if you buy it. Other people hire lawyers to delegate them paper work to claim for the free land spot but the cost of lawyers service might as much or equal to the cost of the land plot if you buy it.

I am not sure what should be done in such situation and what is the best advice here.

Also we have very bad social welfare. An average pensioner receives a state pension around 1700 UAH (around 63.36 USD) which is clear not enough to buy a food and pay for utilities services.
I am 31 years old. When I retire and will not be able to work I wouldn't be able to afford for living. What should I do to receive some passive income which could cover my expenses on food and utilities in the future if I survive till that time?

In the past I received several job offers to relocate to US. However, I have health issues and I need someone to be around me. I fainted three times. Two of these cases were when I was participating in competitive programming contests all night long and I had exhausted myself and I could die if no one were around me to call the ambulance. So I cannot just relocate alone and I don't have a wife or a girlfriend to relocate with a wife. My mother and my grandmother also do have health issues, mostly hypertension, so I can't leave them as well.

Also if I quit now and use my savings to pay for my expenses I will run out of money in a half a year.

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question is "I would like to stop working". This is difficult for almost anyone to do at age 31. Your savings (net worth) covering 6 months of expenses is a good "emergency fund" but not enough to live on, no matter how you invest it; you need more capital to generate enough passive income.

As a young person, your *ability to work* is likely your most valuable asset, so you will need to spend a while longer working for a living. You seem somewhat fortunate to have work opportunities in a rewarding field (programming). If you dislike your current job, think about how to use your skills to land a better one.

Also, continue to minimize your expenses and save as much as possible. I am not familiar with the cost of food in Ukraine, but I wonder if that can be reduced since even in most parts of the US, it is possible to eat (*frugally*) on USD186 per person per month.

If you can work in the US, that would make a big difference (higher expenses, but higher salary and the possibility of sending more money back home). If you are concerned about being alone, you could live with roommates (also reducing expenses). You could work standard hours and not do all-night programming contests. You are concerned about the health of your mother and grandmother, but it is not clear whether your presence is essential.

Overall, you may be feeling desperate and looking for a magic solution, but you should try to evaluate all your options and take advantage of the career opportunities you have. Then at some point, the day when you can realistically retire and live on passive income will arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Land, probably - you aren't going to lose land unless the government starts nationalizing it or similar freaky scenario, and you should be able to rent it out for more than you get taxed for it (provided there is sufficient demand for it. Usually, there is, but I don't know the exact situation in Ukraine). Unlike renting out apartments, it doesn't require you to put forth nearly as much work - being a landlord can easily be a full-time job that demands frequent investments, whereas renting out a field for a farmer that then grows whatever he wants there is usually a lot less demanding in both time and money.

Only problem is, while it's a relatively safe and simple way to get passive income, that income usually isn't very high and it's going to take very, very long for the land to "pay for itself". It's not something you can really afford doing without having a large amount of capital in the first place. Investing in real estate could bring you more profit more quickly, but it's also riskier and does require more work out of you.

In your situation, it seems like you'll just need to keep working.

Answer (score 0):

If the government provides the apartments then that is the inflation hedge. Otherwise, anyone can make themselves rich by building their own house for the cost of materials and never paying rent again.

But welcome to the world of living paycheck-to-paycheck.

A plan to find investments that allow for quitting work sounds very risky. It would be better to hold long term growth investments or have income investments that just supplement the work income.